# Synchronization between parent and child thread (Child thread "on monitor")

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety, monitors

I'm fairly new to Java in general and concurrent programming in particular, so forgive me if this is a newbie question.

I have a thread (a server) which is managing a collection of child threads (each thread representing a session between a client and the server).  The server maintains a collection of sessions, and when the session ends, it signals the parent server that it's finished so the server can remove it from the session collection.

I'm told that ArrayLists need to be protected if you intend to use them with threads, and ints can also have issues unless synchronised, so methods that make use of both are synchronised.

The relevant portions of the server and session objects follow.

```
public class Server {

    private int             listenPort      = 0;
    private ServerSocket    serverSocket    = null;
    private List<Session>   sessions        = new ArrayList ();
    private int             lastId          = 0;

    /**
     * Start listening for clients to process
     * 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @todo Maintain a collection of Clients so we can send global messages
     * @todo Provide an escape condition for the loop
     */
    synchronized public void run () throws IOException {

        Session newSession;

        // Client listen loop
        while (true) {
            //int sessionId = this.Sessions.
            newSession = this.initSession (++this.lastId);
            this.sessions.add (newSession);
            //this.Sessions.add (newSession);
            new Thread (newSession).start ();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Socket accept () throws IOException {
        return this.getSocket().accept ();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param closedSession 
     */
    synchronized public void cleanupSession (Session closedSession) {
        this.sessions.remove (closedSession);
    }
}
```

This is the Session class:

```
public class Session implements Runnable {
    private Socket              clientSocket    = null;
    private Server              server          = null;
    private int                 sessionId       = 0;

    /**
     * Run the session input/output loop
     */
    @Override
    public void run () {
        CharSequence    inputBuffer, outputBuffer;
        BufferedReader  inReader;

        try {
            this.sendMessageToClient ("Hello, you are client " + this.sessionId);
            inReader    = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (this.clientSocket.getInputStream (), "UTF8"));
            do {
                // Parse whatever was in the input buffer
                inputBuffer     = this.requestParser.parseRequest (inReader);
                System.out.println ("Input message was: " + inputBuffer);

                // Generate a response for the input
                outputBuffer    = this.responder.respond (inputBuffer);
                System.out.println ("Output message will be: " + outputBuffer);

                // Output to client
                this.sendMessageToClient (outputBuffer.toString ());

            } while (!"QUIT".equals (inputBuffer.toString ()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger (Session.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            this.cleanupClient ();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Terminate the client connection
     */
    public void cleanupClient () {
        try {
            this.streamWriter   = null;
            this.clientSocket.close ();
            this.server.cleanupSession (this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger (Session.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param clientSocket 
     */
    public Session (Server owner, int sessionId) throws IOException {
        System.out.println ("Class " + this.getClass () + " created");

        this.server         = owner;
        this.sessionId      = sessionId;
        this.clientSocket   = this.server.accept ();

        System.out.println ("Session ID is " + this.sessionId);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is in the session's CleanupClient method.  When the CleanupSession method in the Server is tagged as Synchronized, the Session threads don't appear to terminate.  They instead, according to Netbeans, go into a state named "On Monitor".

My attempts to find out what this meant and what to do about it weren't helpful.  I did find out that the monitor is like a space that can only be occupied by a single thread, and other threads have to wait their turn to use it, and this is how concurrency is achieved in Java.  I couldn't find an explanation, however, why a child thread calling a synchronized method in the parent class would trigger the thread going apparently permanently into this state, or what to do about it.

I did discover that if the cleanupSession method in the Server class is not marked as synchronized, then the threads do terminate as I expected them to do.  However, if I need to synchronize to maintain thread safety, then I can't just leave the method unsynchronized and trust to luck.

I'm obviously missing something basic, but I'm not sure what.  If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong here, I'd appreciate it.

(Addendum: I expect there's some other class of Collection I should be using rather than an ArrayList, and knowing what it is would certainly be great in solving this particular case, but I'd also like feedback in how to avoid this problem in the general case where the only option available is synchronizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by Antimony, you get dead-lock because both methods of Server synchronize on the same object (namely, `Server` instance) and `run()` method never releases lock.

On the other hand, you still need some kind of inter-thread sycnhronization to correctly update `sessions` list (w/o synchronization, you would get two problems: lack of changes visibility and data races).

So, one solution is to synchronize only the smallest possible portion of code: the very access to `sessions` (you don't need to use `this.` everywhere, only where local name shadows name of instance variable):

```
...
public void run () throws IOException {

    Session newSession;

    // Client listen loop
    while (true) {
        ...
        newSession = initSession (++lastId);
        synchronized (this) {
            sessions.add (newSession);
        }
        ...
    }
}

public void cleanupSession (Session closedSession) {
    synchronized (this) {
        sessions.remove (closedSession);
    }
}
```

You right in that `List` isn't a best fit here, you need `HashMap` instead, since all you do is adding new clients and searching for clients, and order in which clients are stored in collection isn't important (even if it's important, it's better to use some ordered `Map`, like `TreeMap`, to improve performance). So, you can change your `Server` code to:

```
private Map<Integer, Session> sessions        = new HashMap<IntegerPatternConverter, Session>();

    ...
    // Client listen loop
    while (true) {
        int key = ++lastId;
        newSession = initSession (key);
        synchronized (this) {
            sessions.put (key, newSession);
        }
        new Thread (newSession).start ();
    }
...
public void cleanupSession (int closedSessionKey) {
    synchronized (this) {
        sessions.remove (closedSessionKey);
    }
}
```

After this change, you may get rid of `synchronized` altogether by using `Map` with built-in synchronization: `ConcurrentHashMap`.

However, this is better to be done after you get basics of Java concurrent programming. For this purpose *Java Concurrency in Practice* is a good place to start. The best introductory Java book I've read (with a nice part about concurrency) is *The Java Programming Language* by Gosling and Holmes.

Comment: Thanks.  I've covered a few Java modules during the course of my studies, but this is the first stuff I've done with concurrency.  Clearly there's still a lot for me to learn.

Comment: Also, as I think I read in Clean Code, ints need to be synchronised or replaced with AtomicInteger, so I switched the code over to using AtomicInteger.

Comment: @GordonM in your code there only three `ints`: in server, `listenPort` and `lastId` are accessed only from the single thread (th e one which executes `Server.run()` method), so they don't need to be synchronized. Same applies to the only `int` in client. You need synchronization only when some data can be accessed by more than one thread during it's lifetime.

Comment: The lastId one gets incremented so I think that one either needs to be synchronised or an AtomicInteger.  Or at least that's the impression I got from the Clean Code book.  Maybe I'm overthinking it.  The others don't change value so having them be ints is fine.

Comment: @GordonM to repeat, you need to synchronize access to data only when it's accessed (read or written) from more than one thread. In this case, synchronization is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've got deadlock.

Your `Server.run` method permanently holds on to the `Server` monitor. Since `cleanupSession` also tries to enter this monitor, every attempt to call it from a different thread will deadlock as long as a server is running.

Anyway, sychronized doesn't do what you want it to. I'd recommend looking into `java.util.Concurrency`.